# Idiomatic Way for Updating Repository in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, spring-data

I am using Kotlin with my spring boot application and I am using Spring-JPA. I have defined my entities as such

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
data class Customer(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long? = null,

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column
    val firstName: String,

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column
    val lastName: String,

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column
    val email: String,

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    val createdAt: Date,

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    val updatedAt: Date? = null
)

@Repository
interface CustomerRepository : CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
   fun findById(id: Long): Customer
}

@Service
class MyService(private val repository: CustomerRepository) {


   fun update(id: Long, firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String):Customer {
       val customer = repository.findById(id)
       return repository.save(customer.copy(firstName=firstName, lastName=lastName, email=email)) // the reason for the copy as the attributes are val
   }
}
```

The example above is one way the update can be handled. The other way would be to make the Entity to use `var` instead of `val` so that it can be modified. What would be the recommended way to do this in Kotlin?

Comment: Of course it must be mutable. The principle of JPA is to deal with managed entities, that you can modify, and whose state is tracked and automatcally made persistent. Using a data class is a poor choice for an entity, too: its equals() and hashCode() implementations wouldn't be correct and entities need a no-arg constructor.

Comment: The no-arg part is resolved by kotlin compiler plugin `"kotlin-jpa"`. As for equals and hashcode, yep you do have a point there

Comment: Interestingly so many articles on the net uses data classes https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-jpa, https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/06/kotlin-spring-working-jpa-data-classes/. One article https://kotlinexpertise.com/hibernate-with-kotlin-spring-boo talks about the hashcode issue but it also uses `val`, so not sure how the update works

Comment: The thing is if you make your entities immutable, you lose the huge advantage that JPA has: automatically persisting the state of the entities. Instead of relying on JPA to do it, you need to track which entities have been "modified" (i.e. copied), and remember to all save them at the end. And, even if it works, you're actually lying to yourself by claiming all these properties are val, since they need to be modified by Hibernate. You thus end up with vals which are effectively mutable. I much prefer to keep the dirty-checking of JPA, and to declare my vars as vars.

Comment: What I use, though, is lateinit vars for non-null properties: it's my responsibility to initialize them before reading them when creating new entities, and I know JPA will always initialized them before I read them when loading them. That still gives me the benefit of never-null Kotlin properties.

Comment: I think many bloggers are so excited about the conciseness of data classes that they abuse them, and don't really think about all their generated code, that doesn't fit with JPA. Or they simply don't master JPA enough.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet for your comments. Reading more, yes you are right on the dirt checking part also. I guess my usage is always explicitly calling the `save` method to save updated data and not depending on dirty check is the reason why I never faced this issue. I guess it all boils down to how you use it, if you use it t just read and write via repository then I guess no issue using data classes but if you depend on dirty check or you store in hasmap or set then yep using data classes is not right

Comment: One interesting thing I noticed is for some reason even when the `hashCode` is not same for before and after saving into db, the `equals` is true, which I have no idea why